# retrieving the text value from 2 textareas

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I am using the following jquery/backbone.js code snippet to get the text values from 2 textareas on the page and write them to two labels in another area on the page.

```
this.input.each(function () {
    val = val + ($(this).val());
});

toDoList.create({ title: val });
```

The code successfully gets the data from the 2 textareas, but when it displays that data in the label, it is displaying it as one label.

So if the two values of the textareas are 'foo' and 'bar', it just shows:

```
<label>foobar</label>
```

I assume this is because I am just getting the textarea values in the loop and not separating them.

Is there a way to rewrite this so I can output something like:

```
<label>foo</label>
<label>bar</label>
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need separate labels, create them within the loop. The concatenation of the two values becomes redundant.

```
this.input.each(function () {
    toDoList.create({ title: $(this).val() });
});
```

Comment: this is great and works, but what if you wanted to give each label a different class?  Like <label class='foo'>  and <label class='bar'>?  thanks

Comment: That would depend on the parameters available in your `create` method. You're probably best starting a new question for that.